# UWP client server in local machine

Tags: tcp, uwp, loopback

I'm developing an standard TCP client-server application in UWP. The server is going to be running in a RaspberryPi and I don't have it available all the time.

I've read that UWP does not allow you to use TCP client servers in the same machine (why tho?) I tried connecting the ethernet and the wifi and forcing the server and the client to be in different ifaces (therefore different IP's) but .. nah, did not fool the system XD

Do somebody know a quick way to work it around ? (I mean .. creating a virtual machine an installing visual studio there does not really sounds like a solution)

Comment: Both your client and server sides are UWP app right?  They are both need running on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: no no, just the server needs to be UWP. The client is actually gonna be micro-python running in ESP6288 and I was coding a simulator of it in C# WPF just for convenience (is what I code professionally)

Answer (score 0):

> no no, just the server needs to be UWP. The client is actually gonna be micro-python running in ESP6288

If I understand correctly, according to the description from you, the server side and client side are not in the same device, they should work well.

> I've read that UWP does not allow you to use TCP client servers in the same machine (why tho?)

If you just mean server and client side on the same device and the server side is UWP app, for this is just not allowed. You could check the note of [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).

> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot normally be used for interprocess communication between a UWP app and a different process (a different UWP app or a desktop app) because this is restricted by network isolation.

So that stream socket communication is restricted by network isolation.

> I was coding a simulator of it in C# WPF just for convenience

You may try to change the communicate way. For example, using [app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). You could try to exchange data by app service which is a supported way for communication in the same device.

Comment: mi scenario is super simple, and I thought it was well explained in the question but .. let me clarify it. I'm developing a client-server application where the server will be a UWP in a raspi and the client will be distributed in other technologies. So the real scenario will work. But for convenience I would like to test it locally. So I open my UWP server. I create a client in any other language.. and I try to connect to it. And it does not work. And moving to app service is not an option. and using different machines is not what I want. I'm asking if there is a way to ignore the isolation

Comment: @javirs "I'm asking if there is a way to ignore the isolation". No, as I mentioned, just not allowed.